# Work account disable automatic home screen shortcuts

Tags: google-play-store, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

(LG v30+ android 8.0.0, app drawer enabled)
I found out how to use work accounts to get another version of apps without needing app cloner (I don't need the fancy things it does and it's kinda shady). But the play store it has automatically adds apps to my home screen. The personal play store doesn't. Here's why this is weird: the setting was moved from Play Store to home screen settings (I've checked both places and can't find the setting but that's what I read). This means the two *should* behave the exact same in this regard. Any thoughts?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this part: "*Here's why this is weird: the setting was moved from Play Store to home screen settings (I've checked both places and can't find the setting but that's what I read).*", but have you checked the settings from *the work profile's Play Store app*?

Comment: Yes, both settings are identical in not showing the check-box that most guides refer to